# Xcode 7 PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

When I tried to build project from command line, I got the following message from xcodebuild:

> xcodebuild[10713:1209993] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in
>   compatibility UUID F41BD31E-2683-44B8-AE7F-5F09E919790E for plug-in at
>   path '~/Library/Application
>   Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/SparkInspectorXcodePlugin.xcplugin'
>   not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs

I installed Spark Inspector a year ago, and deleted it about 6 months ago.

Is there a way to reset Xcode so that it doesn't know there is such a plugin.

So far I have tried re-install Xcode, delete all the reference data. They didn't work.

Answer (score 33):

If you're looking to uninstall the plugin:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/PluginName.xcplugin
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/PluginName
```

Instructions pulled from http://alcatraz.io/

Comment: Also check `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Plug-ins` for old plugins to remove